# Analysis: Integration (Riemann/Step functions)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Using the definition of the integral of a continuous function, and
>   that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} j = (2^n-1)2^{n-1}$ to show that
>   $\int_0^1x \ dx = \frac{1}{2}$

I'm having trouble even starting this question as I'm not sure how to take advantage of the sum given.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, it is integrable. Hence **any** Darboux sum converges to integral of $f$ when partition's tightness tends to $0$. Now I suggect you to consider the simplest partition $\Delta_j:=[\frac{j}{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n}]$ with points $\xi_j=\frac{j}{2^n}$, where $j=0,\ldots, 2^{n}-1$